# Why wouldn't a public method in application.rb be available to all views and controllers via helper:all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I thought the `helper:all` in the following `application.rb` would make `current_user` available to every controller and view?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper :all
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter { |c| Authorization.current_user = c.current_user }

  def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end

  def current_user
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
    @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
  end

  ...

  private

  ...

  protected

  ...

end
```

My views call the `current_user` method like this:

```
- if current_user
  = link_to "Logout", logout_path
```

For which I get this response:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<#<Class:0x007f971d812a48>:0x007f972050c378>
```

What am I missing?

Many thanks,

Steven.

PS I have experimented with this in the controller tied to the view that is failing:

```
before_filter :current_user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the doc:](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper)

> When the argument is the symbol :all, the controller will include all
>   helpers beneath ActionController::Base.helpers_dir (defaults to
>   app/helpers/*/.rb under RAILS_ROOT).

You're looking for:

```
helper_method :current_user, :current_user_session
```